# Can we show some dynamic text along with the marker on Google maps in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter

[image: text]

Is it possible to achieve sth like this image in Flutter? I'm using google_maps_flutter plugin to display the GoogleMap on screen, and I've used BitmapDescriptor to change icon of the map marker.
Now I'm just looking for some way to display the text below the marker.

Answer (score 2):

you can use svg file or svg Strings as  BitmapDescriptor  and you can put any text

to convert svg string or file to BitmapDescriptor

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

Future<BitmapDescriptor> bitmapDescriptorFromSvgAsset(BuildContext context, String price) async {
    // Read SVG file as String
    // String svgString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assetName,);
    // Create DrawableRoot from SVG String
    String svgStrings='''<svg width="75" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <path stroke="#000" id="svg_1" d="m74.14781,0.22566l-73.83144,-0.00774l0,31.59256l30.27788,0l5.12395,17.65467c0.04658,0.00774 3.86625,-17.02746 3.86625,-17.02746c0,0 34.48279,0 34.42362,-0.00774c0.00739,0.00097 0.01513,-0.5015 0.02299,-1.38155c0.00393,-0.44003 0.0079,-0.97446 0.01188,-1.58755c0.00398,-0.61309 0.00796,-1.30486 0.01193,-2.05955c0.02677,-7.20252 0.04414,-12.03835 0.05589,-15.41562c0.01175,-3.37727 0.0179,-5.29597 0.02223,-6.66423c0.00433,-1.36826 0.00686,-2.18608 0.00844,-2.71689c0.00158,-0.53081 0.00223,-0.77459 0.00281,-0.99479c0.00058,-0.2202 0.00109,-0.4168 0.00154,-0.58784c0.00044,-0.17104 0.00082,-0.31653 0.00112,-0.4345c0.0003,-0.11796 0.00053,-0.2084 0.00069,-0.26935c0.00015,-0.06095 0.00023,-0.0924 0.00023,-0.0924c-0.0102,3.52301 -0.01745,6.03945 -0.02249,7.80293c-0.00505,1.76348 -0.00789,2.77399 -0.00928,3.28516c-0.00139,0.51116 -0.00132,0.52297 -0.00054,0.28903c0.00077,-0.23394 0.00225,-0.71362 0.0037,-1.18544c0.00144,-0.47182 0.00284,-0.93578 0.00419,-1.38991c0.00135,-0.45413 0.00266,-0.89844 0.00393,-1.33095c0.00126,-0.43251 0.00248,-0.85323 0.00364,-1.26018c0.00116,-0.40696 0.00228,-0.80015 0.00334,-1.17762c-0.02728,9.05903 -0.02086,7.04596 -0.0151,5.15867c0.00576,-1.88729 0.01086,-3.64879 0.0151,-5.15867c0.00848,-3.01976 0.01351,-5.03301 0.01351,-5.03301z" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#78c188"/>
  <text  y="16.77155" x="24.02531" fill="#ffffff">$price</text>

</svg>''';
    DrawableRoot svgDrawableRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(svgStrings, null,);

    // toPicture() and toImage() don't seem to be pixel ratio aware, so we calculate the actual sizes here
    MediaQueryData queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    double devicePixelRatio = queryData.devicePixelRatio;
    double width = 75 * devicePixelRatio; // where 32 is your SVG's original width
    double height = 50 * devicePixelRatio; // same thing

    // Convert to ui.Picture
    ui.Picture picture = svgDrawableRoot.toPicture(size: Size(width, height));

    // Convert to ui.Image. toImage() takes width and height as parameters
    // you need to find the best size to suit your needs and take into account the
    // screen DPI
    ui.Image image = await picture.toImage(width.toInt(), height.toInt());
    ByteData bytes = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
}
```

for create marker with icon

```
Future<void> createicon(lat,lang) async {
    marker.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('1'),
        icon: await bitmapDescriptorFromSvgAsset(context, 'Hello'),
        position: LatLng(lat, lang)));
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```